# How to prove the divergence of the following sum: $\sum^{\infty}_{x=1}\cot^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{1+x^2+x}\right]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

I'm having difficulty proving the divergence of the following infinite sum :

[Note: Here, $\cot^{-1}$ is inverse $\cot$, i.e. arccot]

$$\sum^{\infty}_{x=1}\cot^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{1+x^2+x}\right]$$

---

I tried the **ratio test** as well as the **root test**, but all give indecisive results. Please help me prove the divergence of the above sum (*and please do elaborate, ideally without skipping much steps, if using other limit tests as I'm not familiar with them*).

Answer (score 6):

Recall that $\def\arccot{\operatorname{arccot}}\arccot 0 = \frac\pi 2$, hence, for $x \to \infty$
$$ \arccot \frac 1{1 + x + x^2} \to \arccot 0 = \frac\pi 2 \ne 0$$
So, as the sequence of the terms does not converge to zero, the series cannot converge.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I missed this... sigh..

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\operatorname{arccot}\dfrac1{1+x+x^2}=\dfrac\pi2-\arctan\dfrac1{1+x+x^2}$$

$$\arctan\dfrac1{1+x+x^2}=\arctan\dfrac{x+1-x}{1+x(1+x)}=\arctan(x+1)-\arctan x$$

which is a Telescoping Series